# Случайное число без Random

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Как в языке `Java` получить случайное число в диапазоне без `Math.random()`?

Answer (score 4):

Алгоритм на основе текущего времени:

```
long rangeBegin = 0L;
long rangeEnd = 100L;

long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long randomNumber = rangeBegin + currentTime % (rangeEnd - rangeBegin);
```

Answer (score 3):

Довольно часто в качестве случайного значения можно использовать текущую дату со временем, например, взять число миллисекунд. Естественно, это подходит только для случая, когда нам нужно всего одно случайное число, либо они запрашиваются достаточно редко и недетерминированно.

Answer (score 3):

Если не хотите использовать `java.util.Random` напишите свой генератор псевдослучайных чисел. Это не так уж и сложно

Немного модифицированный пример из [gnu](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html) реализации стандартной библиотеки `java`

```
public static int next(long seed) {
    int bits = 32;
    seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
    return (int) (seed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

Добавлю еще пару безумных примеров:

```
public static int next() {
    List<Integer> array = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    Collections.shuffle(array);
    return array.get(0);
}
```

Или вот так:

```
public static int next() throws Exception {
    final AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(8_000, 8, 2, true, true);
    final DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    final TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

    line.open(format);
    line.start();
    int bufferSize = (int) format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameSize();
    byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];

    int result = 0;
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        int count = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (count > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            for (byte b : buffer) {
                result += b;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Чтобы последний пример работал, нужно иметь микрофон и шуметь во время работы метода)

Answer (score 1):

```
new Random().ints(min,(max+1)).findFirst().getAsInt();
```